# Updating nested state in react immutably

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React application, I have an object called `parameters` in state which represents a tree.

Here is my `parameters` object:

```
{
    "Access_List": {
        "state": "override",
        "value": {
            "88": {
                "state": "inherit",
                "value": [{
                    "ip": {
                        "state": "inherit",
                        "value": "19.1.1.1"
                    },
                    "mask": {
                        "state": "override",
                        "value": "0.0.0.0"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want a generic way to update any leaf value down the tree. How can I achieve this ? For example, i want to update the value in `ip`.

I know that I can recursively iterate over the `parameters` object and give each node a key which represents its path in the tree. For example the `ip` would be

```
"ip":{
        "state":"inherit",
        "value":"19.1.1.1",
        "key":"Access_List.value.88.value.0.ip"  
}
```

Then I can use lodash `deepClone` function to make a deep copy of the state, then mutate the value of ip using lodash `set` as follows:

```
set(parameters, `${key}.value`, NEW_VALUE)
```

and finally set the new state.

This way will cause all my children to re-render. How can I immutably update the state knowing the path to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) or [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). This lets you easily update nested objects immutable.

For immer you would write it like this:

```
produce(yourObject, objectState => {
       objectState.Access_List.value.88.value[0].ip.value = 0
});
```

For immutability-helper:

```
update(yourObject, {
     Access_List: {
         value: {
             88: {
                 value: {
                    [0]: {
                        ip: {
                           value :{$set: 0}
                       }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
});
```

These are great ways to update your objects and stay immutable, which can greatly improve your performance. Both return the new, immutable updated object.
It only updates the path you want to update and keeps these object you do not want to update the same.

If you use redux, mobx, or pure functions/components, this will prevent unnecessary rerenders, because only the components which use the updated parts of your object will be rerendered.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking at it wrongly. Immutability is about not changing only parts of an object. That is the right way. What you are probably needing is a way to prevent unnecessary rerender. You can achieve that by using `PureComponent` or by own implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate` - depends on your usage of the `parameters` object. Another thing to think about is if you really need everything in one object to be passed through your app.